# Angular UI-Router: nested views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

[image] I have  two col layout with header and footer. Header has page navigation (GetStarted, Component). Of the 2 columns, one is for sidenav and other is for main content.
    When "GetStarted" nav is active, sidenav is populated with respective links (overview, examples)
    When "Component" nav is active, sidenav is populated with respective links (checkbox, alert)

Upon clicking "Overview" link  area is populated with its data

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#checkbox--default">Default</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#checkbox--disabled">Disabled</a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="content__main__tab__content col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <form id="checkbox--default">
        <div class="input__checkbox--default" id="checkbox--default">
        <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Default</legend>
                <label for="gi-checkbox">Checkbox Label
                <div class="checkbox-input-wrapper group__input-wrapper">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="gi-checkbox">
                </div>
                </label>
          </fieldset>             
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div> 
      </form>
</section>
```

Main content has 2 nav tabs for checbox states (default & disable). By clicking the "default" its content must be displayed and same goes for disabled. I'm new to angular and I kinda got first level nested view working. But couldn't the whole thing working. here is the code sample

**index.html**

```
    <body ng-app="mendouiApp" id="mendo__home" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".scrollspy">    
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home"><img src="images/gi-logo.png" alt="logo"/></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a ui-sref="home">Get Started</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="components">Components</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container  -->
        </nav><!-- /.navbar -->

         <div class="wrapper" ui-view></div> <!--/.container-->
```

**component.html**

```
    <div class="content__wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="content__secondary content__secondary--l scrollspy">
              <ul id="sidenav-fixed-l" class="nav hidden-xs hidden-sm affix-top" data-spy="affix">
                <li>
                    <h5>COMPONENTS</h5>
                </li>
                <li ng-repeat="item in componentsList">
                    <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}" ng-cloak>{{item.name}}</a> 
                </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div ui-view></div>      
        </div> <!--/.row-->
      </div> <!--/.content-wraper-->
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){
    var mendouiApp = angular.module('mendouiApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.router.stateHelper']);

    mendouiApp.constant('COMPONENTS_LIST', {
        name: 'sidenav',
        templateUrl: '../components/components.list.html',
        abstract: true,
        children: [{
            name: 'alerts',
            url: '/alerts',
            templateUrl: '../components/alerts/alerts.html'
        }]
    });

    mendouiApp.config(function($stateHelperProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider, COMPONENTS_LIST) {
        $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $stateHelperProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '../gettingstarted.html',
                controller: 'getStartedController'
            })
            .state('layouts', {
                url: '/layouts',
                templateUrl: '../layouts.html'
            })
            .state('screenpatterns', {
                url: '/screenpatterns',
                templateUrl: '../screenpatterns.html'
            })
            .state('yogi', {
                url: '/yogi',
                templateUrl: '../yogi.html'
            })
            .state('components', {
                url: '/components', 
                templateUrl: '../components.html',
                controller: 'componentsController'
            })
            .state(COMPONENTS_LIST, {
                keepOriginalNames: true
            })
            .state('components.button', {
                url: '/button',
                templateUrl: '../components/button/button.html'
            })          .state('components.checkbox', {
                url: '/checkbox',
                templateUrl: '../components/checkbox/checkbox.html'
            })
            .state('components.forms', {
                url: '/forms',
                deepStateRedirect: true,
                sticky: true,
                views: {
                    '': { templateUrl: '..forms.html' },
                    'inline@components.forms': {
                        templateUrl: '../components/forms/form-inline/forminline.html'
                    },
                    'default@components.forms': {
                        templateUrl: '../components/forms/form-default/formdefault.html'
                    },
                    'multicolumn@components.forms': {
                        templateUrl: '../components/forms/form-multicolumn/formmulticolumn.html'
                    }
                }           
            });
            // use the HTML5 History API
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
              enabled: true,
              requireBase: false
            });
    });

    mendouiApp.controller('componentsController', ['$scope', '$state', 'sideNavService', function($scope, $state, sideNavService, COMPONENTS_LIST){
        $scope.componentsList = sideNavService.components;
        $scope.componentsnav = COMPONENTS_LIST.children;
        $scope.go = function(tab) {
            $state.go(tab.name);
        }
    }]);
    mendouiApp.controller('getStartedController', ['$scope', '$state', 'sideNavService', 'fixedSideNavService', function($scope, $state, sideNavService, fixedSideNavService ){
        $scope.getstartedList = sideNavService.getstarted;
    }]);

    /*** This is for the external url reference ***/
    mendouiApp.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $window, fixedSideNavService, copyToClipBoardService) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $state, $stateParams) {
                if (toState.external) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $window.open(toState.url, '_self');
                }
        });
        $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event){
            fixedSideNavService.fixedsidenav();
            copyToClipBoardService.copytoclipboard();
        });

        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        $state.transitionTo('home');
    });
    })();
```

**service.js**

```
angular.module('mendouiApp').service('sideNavService', function() {
  return {
    "getstarted" : [
        {
            "name" : "Overview",
            "link" : "home.overview"
        }
        {
            "name" : "Summary",
            "link" : "home.overview"
        }

    ],
    "components" : [
        {
            "name" : "Alerts",
            "link"  :"components.alert"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Button",
            "link"  :"components.button"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Button Groups",
            "link"  :"components.buttongroup"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Button Icons",
            "link"  :"components.buttonicons"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Checkbox",
            "link"  :"components.checkbox"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Datepicker",
            "link"  :"components.datepicker"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Forms",
            "link" : "components.forms"
        }

    ]
 };
});
```

Comment: What is the question? Please clean this up a little bit, is a complete mess and really hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was a bit messy, but after a while playing with I could understand I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/canastro/c4kt2myc/2/ I hope it works as you were expecting.

The main thing to focus on here is:

```
.state("root.components.button", {
    url: '/components/button',
    views: {
        'main@': {
            template: `
                <div>
                    <a ui-sref="root.components.button.default">default</a>
                    <a ui-sref="root.components.button.disabled">disabled</a>
                    <div ui-view="buttonsContent"></div>
                </div>
            `
        }
    }
})
.state("root.components.button.default", {
    url: '/components/button/default',
    views: {
        'buttonsContent@root.components.button': {
            template: 'root.components.button.default'
        }
    }
})
.state("root.components.button.disabled", {
    url: '/components/button/disabled',
    views: {
        'buttonsContent@root.components.button': {
            template: 'root.components.button.disabled'
        }
    }
})
```

In the first level you have a abstract route so you can always have your basic layout present.

Then in the Started / Components routes, you load content into the `main` and `side` ui-views.

In all of the Started and Component child routes you just override the `main` views.

And finally, in the last level you need to say you want to fill the content of a ui-view created in the previous state, by doing something like `VIEWNAME@STATENAME`.

Comment: thanks for taking time to help me. the code above i posted also kinda does that. But where i'm stuck is upon populating the main and side ui-views, now the user will be clicking the links from sidenav. For example "say checkbox". Now the main ui-view is poplulated with its content. this content has nav tabs like (stacked, disabled,..) By default first tab content should be displayed it the view below the tab. On clicking disabled, uiview will be changed with its content. Attaching the screen pdf

Comment: Updated the answer, i think it might match what you need now